# Swift NSDictionary JSON Array to String Convert Time consuming

Tags: arrays, json, swift, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I am converting NSDictionary to string and storing it in SQLite database and again retrieving from the database and converting a string to NSDictionary by using the below two methods {mentioned in the code  below this para}. But it is taking a lot of time to convert  both ways {array to string & vice versa} if we store multiple dictionaries in one SQLite database table.  Is there any solution to convert complete NSArray or complete NSDictionary to string and vice-versa in less time?

```
    func jsonDictionary(jsonData:NSDictionary)-> String
        {
            
            var error : NSError?
            
            let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonData, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
            
            let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String

            return jsonString
            
        }
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> NSDictionary {
        var json=text
        json = json.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
//        json = json.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
        print(json)
        
        var jsonDictData=NSDictionary()
        if let data = json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            do {
                var jsonDict: NSDictionary? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary
                jsonDictData=jsonDict?.mutableCopy()as! NSMutableDictionary
                print(jsonDictData)
                
            }
            catch
            {
                
            }
        }
        return jsonDictData
    }
```

Comment: `.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n"...` Why are you doing this? Oh right, you're using `.PrettyPrinted`... Then don't use it! Pass empty options instead of `.PrettyPrinted`. // Also, you could save the JSON data as a blob instead of converting to/from String.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I am forced to use the ".stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString...." because i am getting "\n.." while converting from NSDictionary to String. Also i dont know what you mean by "data as a blob instead of converting to/from string ?"

Comment: You think you are forced to but you are wrong. Encode and decode the proper way and you *never* have to do that. // And I'm saying to save your JSON **data** instead of saving its string representation.

Comment: Eric, i am storing each NSDictionary in each row of the SQLite database. But while storing I have to convert the NSDictionary to string to insert into the Database. Because SQLite database takes only string values I am converting JSON data to a string. My problem is that I have vast data and am forced to store each NSDictionary or NSArray as a string in each row of a Single database table. Note I am not an expert in swift but stuck with vast data to manage

Comment: `Because SQLite database takes only string values` Nope. You can store data too. // I've made an answer to explain what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert your JSON data to String, and you certainly shouldn't ever process the JSON string itself anyway.

To save your dictionary as JSON, just convert the dictionary to JSON *data* then save the data:

```
let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(yourDictionary, options: [])
// save `jsonData` in your SQL
```

**Here `jsonData` is your JSON data**. This is what you need to save. Nothing else.

You can save this in an SQL table by saving it as `blob` (a chunk of data) instead of String.

Then to get it back:

```
let jsonData = // get the blob from SQL
if let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []),
    let dict = json as? [String: AnyObject] 
{
    // here `dict` is your dictionary converted from JSON data
}
```

See? No need for converting the JSON data to or from String.

*Last suggestion: don't use NSDictionary and NSArray. Instead, use Swift arrays and Swift dictionaries. It's easier and safer.*